# Слово "изволили" совершенного или несовершенного вида?

Tags: глаголы, аспектология, недопустимая-метка, морфология

И имеет ли коррелят по виду?
Приехавший на повозке мужичок сообщил, что "вотчина сгорела", причем "изволили сгореть и супруга".

Comment: >Достоевский, "Идиот"  
> На третий день по прибытии его в город явился к нему из его деревеньки его староста, верхом, с обожженною щекой и обгоревшею бородой, и возвестил ему, что "вотчина сгорела", вчера, в самый полдень, при чем "изволили сгореть и супруга, а деточки целы остались". Этого сюрприза даже и Барашков, приученный к "синякам фортуны", не мог вынести; он сошел с ума и чрез месяц помер в горячке.

Есть интересная подборка сведений о том, как глаголы в русской грамматике [по видам делили](http://stcreserv.narod.ru/rusling/ryjaya2.html).

Answer (score 3):

Это устаревшее слово, сейчас имеет несов. вид.

Сов.вид используется редко, но, думаю, здесь как раз такое использование, ведь это явно худ. произведение, события прошлые, вполне можно предположить, что тогда была пара изволять-изволить.

Форма изволять употреблялась в церковно-славянском(возможно, и сейчас используется, но в совр. русском ненормативна). Потом появился разговорный омоним изволять-вызволять, освобождать("придется всех изволять из неволи"), а форма изволить стала тяготеть к повелительному использованию (близко к "велеть"), она стала выходить из повсеместного употребления в прежнем значении "изъявлять волю, желать", в 20 веке приобретает ироническое значение вместо уважительного, становится стилистической фигурой.

"изволили сгореть и супруга" - в уважительном значении, по отнощению к высоким чинам, следовательно, возможно сказать, что вид совершенный. Но если это морфологический разбор на оценку,следует сделать оговорку- вид несовершенный в значении совершенного. Есть же двувидовые глаголы(напр.,ранить), но этот как двувидовой не зафиксирован.

Answer (score 2):

1. ГЛАГОЛ «изволить»  (чего или  с  неопр.  ф., несов. вид) имеет значение  «хотеть, желать» с различными добавочными оттенками (устаревший этикет, ирония, подобострастие): Что изволите (желаете)?  Изволите (хотите) чаю? Куда изволите (хотите) ехать?
2. СВОЕОБРАЗНЫЙ УСТОЙЧИВЫЙ ОБОРОТ: связка «изволить» в нужной форме + неопр. форма основного глагола. Вид (сов. или несов.) ЗАДАЕТ ВСЕМУ ОБОРОТУ ОСНОВНОЙ ГЛАГОЛ: Барыня изволит гневаться (= гневается, несов. вид), "изволили сгореть (сгорела, совер. вид) и супруга".

Comment: Изволить - захотеть. Почему "хотеть"? Есть приставка, значит сов. вид.

Comment: 1. Видовые пары часто образуются с помощью приставки (писать - написать), но это не единственный способ. Например: нарЕзать - нарезАть (изменение ударения). Глагол "находиться" имеет приставку, но является  глаголом несовершенного вида (одновидовой глагол). 
2. Ожегов определяет "изволить" как глагол несовершенного вида, когда он используется в значении желать, хотеть. "Что изволите" - это "что хотите". Обратим внимание на личную форму глагола настоящего времени - для глаголов сов. вида это было бы будущее простое время (напишете).

Comment: @Инна, *изволить* не имеет приставки. Следовательно, совершенный вид — *соизволить*.

Comment: Отсутствие приставки не всегда показатель несовершенного вида. Сравните: бросить - сов.в. и подбросить тоже

Answer (score 1):

> "изволили сгореть и супруга".

Зависит от времени написания источника (не имею возможности искать сейчас источник).
Скорее всего здесь обычный совершенный вид, полагающийся по старым нормам без всяких оговорок - т.е. "соизволили".
Современное толкование "изволить" как совершенного вида, неприменимо по смыслу. А если бы действительно требовался несовершенный, употребили бы "изволяла" (от "изволять" - ныне формы совершенно забытой).

Интересно, что с довольно близким глаголом "решить" произошла обратная метаморфоза. Во времена Пушкина это был обычный глагол несовершенного вида, соотвенствующий современному "решать".

Ее тревожит сновиденье.
Не зная, как его понять,
Мечтанья страшного значенье
Татьяна хочет отыскать.
Татьяна в оглавленье кратком
Находит азбучным порядком
Слова: бор, буря, ведьма, ель,
Еж, мрак, мосток, медведь, метель
И прочая. Ее сомнений
Мартын Задека не решит;
Но сон зловещий ей сулит
Печальных много приключений.
Дней несколько она потом
Все беспокоилась о том.

"Е.О.", гл. 5, XXIV

Привожу полность как пример ошибочности подхода, требующего применять современные нормы. Здесь явно несовершенный вид глагола "решить".
Аналогично и в разбираемой фразе "изволить" имеет вид совершенный вопреки современному пониманию.  
(+)
А это не Достоевский часом? Если да, то не *извольте сомневаться*, "изволить" у него - вполне совершенный вид. Будет Интернет - найду примеры.

Answer (score 0):

..."вотчина сгорела", вчера, в самый полдень, при чем "изволили сгореть и супруга, а деточки целы остались". В этом примере "изволили" никак не в значении "хотеть" или "захотеть", скорее, имеется в виду, что так вышло, что они тоже сгорели. В любом случае - действие уже свершившееся, сочетание "изволили сгореть" - составное глагольное сказуемое, где оба глагола использованы в совершенном виде. Кстати - это в подлиннике так написано: "пр*и ч*ём"?